# python3 datetime.datetime.strftime failed to accept utf-8 string format

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

python3 `datetime.datetime.strftime` failed to accept utf-8 string format

what I did is::

```
# encoding: utf-8
import datetime

f = "%Y年%m月%d日"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print( now.strftime(f) )
```

and what I get is:

```
D:\pytools>python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    print( now.strftime(f) )
UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\u5e74' in position 2
: Illegal byte sequence
```

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: works under my Python3.3 in Mac. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: `f` variable should be unicode, add `u` as a prefix: `f = u"%Y年%m月%d日"`. Also `encoding` header for file doesn't look like this, afaik. It looks this way: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: it is ok to use encoding: utf-8. Because coding declare just need to match regular expression coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+)

Comment: I use python3.3 in windows 7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<s>The problem is not in `datetime`, it's in `print`. See [PrintFails](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails)</s>

Ah, it's not exactly that - although it has the same cause, and you're likely to have that problem writing Unicode to stdout. (Using an IDE with a Python shell eg an up-to-date IDLE, avoids this.)

The `strftime()` function which is what `datetime.strftime()` ends up calling, is part of the C standard library, which under Windows/MSVCRT can't deal with Unicode strings. (Although in theory you could work around it by setting code page to 65001 and using UTF-8, there are serious long-standing bugs in the C runtime for that code page.)

Workaround in Python could be to replace out the non-ASCII characters until after the call:

```
strftime('%Y{0}%m{1}%d{2}').format(*'年月日')
```

Or to eschew `strftime` and do it yourself.

This should probably be considered a bug in `time.strftime()` and fixed there, by either of these means. It would make sense to add a Python-native implementation of `strftime` - they have already had to do the same for `strptime` due to other platform bugs in that function.

Comment: I've a try. It still reports the same error without `print` statement.

Comment: In my machine, python3's default encoding is `utf-8`. However, default locale's encoding is `cp936`. I guess this difference causes the issue.

Comment: it is not a print statement problem. change print( now.strftime(f) ) to r = now.strftime(f) print r and you will find that the exception occurs at r= now.strftime(f)

Comment: i read the datetime.py and find it call time.strftime, and i tested it is bug in time.strftime. and the time module is a builtin module. I can do nothing, but use a work around now.

Comment: I changed my computer's locale to avoid changing the code. You can see your current locale by `locale.getdefaultlocale()`. If you're using Windows, these may be helpful: [How can I manually determine the CodePage and Locale of the current OS](https://serverfault.com/a/836221/) & [How do I view and change the system locale settings to use my language of choice?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.html).

Comment: "It would make sense to add a Python-native implementation of strftime - they have already had to do the same for strptime due to other platform bugs in that function." Rather, it would make sense to scrap those functions entirely, in favour of native Python implementations **of well-designed, Pythonic interfaces with Pythonic names**.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> now.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日 %H时%M分%S秒'.encode('unicode- 
 escape').decode()).encode().decode("unicode-escape")

'2018年04月12日 15时55分32秒'
```

Comment: It's crazy, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

my work around

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print( now )



import re

def strftime(datetimeobject, formatstring):
    formatstring = formatstring.replace("%%", "guest_u_never_use_20130416")
    ps = list(set(re.findall("(%.)", formatstring)))
    format2 = "|".join(ps)
    vs = datetimeobject.strftime(format2).split("|")
    for p, v in zip(ps, vs):
        formatstring = formatstring.replace(p, v)
    return formatstring.replace("guest_u_never_use_20130416", "%")

r = strftime(now, "%%%Y年%m月%d日 %%")
print(r)
```

the result is

```
D:\Projects\pytools>python a.py
2013-04-16 20:14:22.518358
%2013年04月16日 %
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem on my windows10, fixed it by:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, 'chinese')
print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y年%m月%d日 %H时%M分%S秒'))
```

result：2017年04月01日 15时56分34秒

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, see below:

```
import datetime
from contextlib import contextmanager
import locale


@contextmanager
def locale_block(local_name: str, lc_var=locale.LC_ALL):
    org_local = locale.getlocale()
    try:
        yield locale.setlocale(lc_var, local_name)
    finally:
        locale.setlocale(lc_var, org_local)


with locale_block('zh'):
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y年%m月%d日'))
```

It will restore the value of the locale after leaving the `with` statement.